# Empty array setState using push method in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, push, setstate

I try to push a specific string called `mendatory1` and `mendatory2` in the empty array in the state.

```
class SignUp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.states = {
      box1: false,
      box2: false,
      box3: false,
      box4: false,
      agreeBox: []
    };
  }
}
```

---

[- Code in image here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pixV.png)

When the `onClick` event occurs `SingleClicked` function activates and it changes the input checked value from false to true which means the checkbox type of input is ticked.

At this time, I want to update the state of an empty array by using `setState`!

```
SingleClicked = e => {
  console.dir(e.target);
  if (e.target.className === "serviceTerm") {
    this.setState({
      box1: !this.state.box1,
      agreeBox: !this.state.box1
        ? this.state.agreeBox.push("mendatory1")
        : this.state.agreeBox
   });
  }
  if (e.target.className === "InfoSecurity") {
    this.SecondClicked(e);
  }
  if (e.target.className === "PromotionSms") {
    this.ThirdClicked(e);
  }
  if (e.target.className === "PromotionMail") {
    this.FourthClicked(e);
  }
};
```

[- Code in image here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/935T4.png)

If I click the other checkbox, the onClick event function 'SingleClicked' will call 'SecondClicked' function which will change the value of the input checked from false to true.

Here, I gave the same logic code, but it makes the error when the `onClick` event occurs:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please add your actual code to the question rather than images of it. Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Your error stems from the first time you set your state. The main issue is with:

```
this.state.agreeBox.push("mendatory1");
```

The [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) does two things, it adds `"mendatory1"` to your `agreeBox` array, and then *returns* the length of the array with the added string. You then proceed to set your `agreeBox` property equal to this number.

So, when you try and push into `agreeBox` again, it is actually a number, not an array. To fix this, you can use [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead of `.push()`. This won't modify `agreeBox` in-place like .push() does, but instead, it returns a new array which you can set in `setState()`:

```
this.state.agreeBox.concat("mendatory1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mutate array state directly and it's cosing the error. 
You can update the state easily using the spread operator. This can be in your `SingleClicked` function:

```
const agreeBox = !this.state.box1 ?
   [...this.state.agreeBox, 'mendatory2'] : [...this.state.agreeBox];
this.setState({
  box1: !this.state.box1,
  agreeBox,
});
```